# Setting orientation for Google Mobile Vision face detector

Tags: ios, google-api, swift4, google-vision

I trying to get Google Mobile Vision to detect faces from a live camera feed. Since I am processing frames I need to set the orientation. The Google Docs say...

> The face detector expects images and the faces in them to be in an upright orientation. If you need to rotate the image, pass in orientation information in the dictionary options with GMVDetectorImageOrientation key. The detector will rotate the images for you based on the orientation value.

How do I get the image orientation and then pass it through the key?

My Dictionary of options...

```
        let options = [GMVDetectorFaceLandmarkType: GMVDetectorFaceLandmark.all.rawValue, GMVDetectorFaceClassificationType: GMVDetectorFaceClassification.all.rawValue, GMVDetectorFaceTrackingEnabled: true] as [String : Any]
```